# Populate username in IdentityServer login page with default value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, identityserver3

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input required name="username" autofocus id="username" type="text"   class="form-control" placeholder="Username"   contenteditable="true"  ng-model="model.username" value="MyDefaultValue" maxlength="100">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input required id="password" name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" ng-model="model.password" maxlength="100" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="form.$invalid">Login</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I wanted "MyDefault" value to be displayed in the login screen as Username value but I can't see any value in login screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done adding this (ng-init="model.username = model.username || 'MyDefaultValue'")
It will take either model.username if it is there nd since for first time model.username is null ,it will take value as 'MyDefaultValue'.

Answer (score 0):

```
**value="{{model.loginUrl}}"** ng-model="model.username" **value="MyDefaultValue"**
```

You have double value attribute here. You should delete first one if you would like to show MyDefaultValue.

Comment: Thanks for correcting my question.I have edited now

Comment: When I delete( ng-model="model.username") from username ,the code seems to work ,but this ( ng-model="model.username") is auto generated code and I am not sure about consequences of modifying the auto-generated code

Comment: Dont delete ng-model just delete value="{{model.loginUrl}}

Comment: can you please see edited question once..If I delete the one you are referring,I don't get my username value filled at the time of login.